# Using jQuery, how do you mimic the form serialization for a select with multiple options selected in a $.ajax call?

Tags: jquery

Below is my $.ajax call, how do I put a selects (multiple) selected values in the data section?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "http://myServer" ,
    dataType: "text",
    data: {
        'service' : 'myService',
        'program' : 'myProgram',
        'start' : start,
        'end' : end ,
        },
    success: function(request) {
      result.innerHTML = request ;
    }   // End success
  }); // End ajax method
```

**EDIT** I should have included that I understand how to loop through the selects selected options with this code:

```
$('#userid option').each(function(i) {
 if (this.selected == true) {
```

but how do I fit that into my data: section?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

how about using an array?

```
data: {
    ...
    'select' : ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'],
    ...
},
```

**edit**: ah sorry, here's the code, a few caveats:

```
'select' : $('#myselectbox').serializeArray(),
```

in order for serializeArray() to work though, all form elements must have a name attribute. the value of `'select'` above will be an array of objects containing the name and values of the selected elements.

```
'select' : [
    { 'name' : 'box', 'value' : 1 },
    { 'name' : 'box', 'value' : 2 }
],
```

the select box to produce the above result would be:

```
<select multiple="true" name="box" id="myselectbox">
   <option value="1" name="option1" selected="selected">One</option>
   <option value="2" name="option2" selected="selected">Two</option>
   <option value="3" name="option3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You probably also want the selector $(":selected #selectbox") where "#selectbox" is your select tag

Comment: when I read the documentation for $.ajax...specifically data:, I got your answer of using an array for 'select'...jQuery serializes parms entered as an array..so you get &select=parm1&select=parm2&select=parm3, etc. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the answer from @Owen, I got this code to work.

For a select box with an id="mySelect" multiple="true"

```
    var mySelections = [];
    $('#mySelect option').each(function(i) {
        if (this.selected == true) {
            mySelections.push(this.value);
        }
    });


    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "http://myServer" ,
      dataType: "text",
      data: {
        'service' : 'myService',
        'program' : 'myProgram',
        'selected' : mySelections
        },
      success: function(request) {
        result.innerHTML = request ;
      }
    }); // End ajax method
```

Comment: ah glad you got it to work :) just a note, serialize() returns the values as &select=param etc... while serializeArray() places it in the structure i detailed above. cheers.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to represent a collection of multiple options selected is to use an **array**, by naming the SELECT tag with a [] suffix.
The problem is that it is not correctly handled by the jQuery method serialize().
For a SELECT like this, infact:

```
<select name="a[]">
    <option value="five">5</option>
    <option value="six">6</option>
    <option value="seven">7</option>
</select>
```

serialize sends this array: a[]=0&a[]=1&a[]=2
received by PHP this way:

```
[a] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 2
    )
```

where real values are lost.

Comment: Why would you assume that this is a PHP question?  Other languages know what to do with an array via POST