# AJAX call on Multiple selection in Select element

Tags: jquery, ajax

How do you make a jQuery AJAX call on selection change of a `select` input enabled for multi-select.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i use this method, only you can see more in post:

[Using jQuery, how do you mimic the form serialization for a select with multiple options selected in a $.ajax call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195058/using-jquery-how-do-you-mimic-the-form-serialization-for-a-select-with-multiple)

```
 var mySelections = [];
        $('#mySelect option').each(function(i) {
                if (this.selected == true) {
                        mySelections.push(this.value);
                }
        });


    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
          url: "http://myServer" ,
          dataType: "text",
          data: {
                'service' : 'myService',
                'program' : 'myProgram',
        'selected' : mySelections
                },
          success: function(request) {
                result.innerHTML = request ;
      }
    }); // End ajax method
```

Comment: How to push both Option text and Option value.

Comment: mySelections.push( { text: $this.text(), value: $this.val() );

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="Myform">
<select name="myoption" id="MyOptions" multiple="multiple">
 <option value="1" selected=""> Value 1 </option>
 <option value="2" selected=""> Value 2</option>
 <option value="3"> Value 3 </option>
</select>
</form>




var Mydata = $('#Myform').serialize();
OR
var Mydata = $('#MyOptions').serialize();

So it gets from all the selected values


$.ajax({
  type: "post",
      url: "http://URL" ,
      dataType: "text",
      data: Mydata,
      success: function(request) {
            result.innerHTML = request ;
  }
});
```

Comment: A little explanation along with your code sample would be better to assist the developer who asked the question