# How to pass multiple select ids to ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I have created multiple select option, onchange i want to pass all multiple select ids to jquery ajax.

presently single select option params is working fine. how to do the same with multiple options?

Here is my select input and script

```js
function update_subscategories_div(id) {
console.log(id);
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/get_subscategories",
    type: "GET",
    data: {
      "parent_id": id
    },
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {
      jQuery("#versionsDiv").html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="customer[category_ids][]" id="customer_category_ids_" onchange="update_subscategories_div(this)" multiple="multiple" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Select a parent category</option>
  <option value="1">option1</option>
  <option value="2">option2</option>
  <option value="3">option3</option>
  <option value="4">option4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax call on Multiple selection in Select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104373/ajax-call-on-multiple-selection-in-select-box)

Comment: OnChange will call every time when you select option in the SelectBox. Is it proper way?

Comment: @visnu yes because on change of this i am showing  subcategories based on this select.

Comment: @SreRoR Can you try $("#customer_category_ids_").serializeArray() to get selected option instead of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code doesn't make much sense...you're passing `id` to the server but this is a HTMLelement, not the selected ID (because you passed `this` to the function). Here's how you can get all the currently selected IDs. This will pass the selection to the server as an array.

N.B. I used a jQuery unobtrusive event handler, which is generally considered to be a better practice than inline event handling code (more visible, more maintainable, separate of code from layout).

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("#customer_category_ids_").change(function() {
    var ids = $(this).val();
    console.log(ids);
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: "/get_subscategories",
      type: "GET",
      data: {
        "ids": ids
      },
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(data) {
        jQuery("#versionsDiv").html(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="customer[category_ids][]" id="customer_category_ids_" multiple="multiple" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Select a parent category</option>
  <option value="1">option1</option>
  <option value="2">option2</option>
  <option value="3">option3</option>
  <option value="4">option4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you ADyson, it is working fine :). thanks a lot.... Followed the same way as you instructed.