# Ajax post only returning first value for multiple select box

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

I have an MVC form that has a select box with the multiple element applied so that the user can select more than one option within the list.

[image]

I then have a ajax post to save this info to a table:

```
$(".save").on("click", function (e) {
   disableButton($(e.currentTarget));
   waitForFinalEvent(function () {
               $.ajax({
                  url: "@Url.Action("Requirements", "Api/Access")",
                  type: "POST",
                  data: {
                    UserId: "@ViewBag.Id",
                    Software: $("#ExtraSoftwareSelect").val(),
                  }
           }).done(function (data) {
              toastr.success("Successfully save information", "Success");
              window.location.href = '@Url.Action("", "")';
           }).fail(function (error) {
              displayError(error);
           }).always(function () {
              enableButton($(e.currentTarget));
           });
   }, 250, "Saving results.");
});
```

My selectbox:

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
    <div class="input-group ">
        <span class="input-group-addon white">Extra Software</span>
        <select class="form-control gray software-select" id="ExtraSoftwareSelect" title="Select Software" multiple></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

My action controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Requirements")]
[CustomApiAuthorize(Roles = UserRole.Manager)]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostRequirements(RequirementsDetails data)
{
      var software = await _slg_Entity.Software.FirstOrDefaultAsync(z => z.Software1 == data.Software);

      var extraSoftware = new UserSoftware
      {
          UserId = data.UserId,
          ExtraSoftware = data.Software,
          SoftwareId = software.Id
      };

      Entity.UserSoftware.Add(extraSoftware);

      await _slg_Entity.SaveChangesAsync();

      return Ok();
}
```

The problem is that the value for that field is only returning the first selected option 'MiniTab'.
I'm not sure how it's meant to come through.. Perhaps it needs to be added to a list somehow? I was hoping it would return a string of the selected separated by commas.

All advice welcome, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using jQuery, how do you mimic the form serialization for a select with multiple options selected in a $.ajax call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195058/using-jquery-how-do-you-mimic-the-form-serialization-for-a-select-with-multiple)

Comment: @TimHunter I tried it, but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You have to post your select box code too. We don't know how you created it

Comment: @Serge updated the post with my select box

Comment: Thanks, but I can't see how did you fill it ? where are all  items from?

Comment: @Serge The options are getting populated by a database via a get method.

Comment: Thanks, can you post Requirements action too pls?

Comment: @Serge Action controller posted

Comment: Thanks, and now the most important. pls post RequirementsDetails class.

Comment: @Serge it's just: **int UserId, string ExtraSoftware, int SoftwareId**.

Comment: I poste my answer, pls try it. it works in my VS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix ajax

```
var softwareArr =  $("#ExtraSoftwareSelect").val().slice();

 $.ajax({
         url: '@Url.Action("Requirements", "Api/Access")',
          type: "POST",
           data: { 
                  details:
                    { 
                      userId: "@ViewBag.Id",
                      extraSoftware: softwareArr
                    }
           },
       success: function (result) {
                .....
            },
            error: function (xhr, exception) {
               ....
            }
       });
```

and fix the RequirementsDetails class

```
public class RequirementsDetails 
{
public int UserId {get; set;}
public string[] ExtraSoftware {get;set;}
}
```

action

```
Route("~/Api/Access/Requirements")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostRequirements(RequirementsDetails details)
.....
```